# how to count the number of check boxes checked in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Btn_Cast_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn_Cast.Click
    Dim Counter As Integer = 0
    If ChkBox_Barton.CheckState = 1 And ChkBox_Martin.CheckState = 1 And ChkBox_Richards.CheckState = 1 Then
        MsgBox("Don't vote for more than 2")
    End If
    Dim Count_Barton As Integer
    Dim Count_Martin As Integer
    Dim Count_Richards As Integer

    If ChkBox_Barton.Checked Then Count_Barton += 1

    If ChkBox_Martin.Checked = 1 Then Count_Martin += 1

    If ChkBox_Richards.CheckState = 1 Then Count_Richards += 1

End Sub
```

Problem is, I'm trying to count it everytime, then let it reset and count again.

Example. I select Barton one time, click vote, then i should be able to select someone new and click vote and it should keep counting.

what can I do?

I need to then display my results. Should I just hold the number in a text or Integer file then display it that way?

Comment: First your declaration of variable Count_Barton,Count_Martin ,Count_Richards  must not be inside  the Btn_Cast_Click event ,because you initialize them Everytime you click vote button

Comment: Did you want to use radio buttons so you can cast one vote at a time, or can you vote for more than one person at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quickly set up your application myself.

Following Code applies to this GUI:

[image]

Code:

```
Public Class VoteCounter

Dim intCountBarton As Integer
Dim intCountMartin As Integer
Dim intCountRichards As Integer

Private Sub ButtonVote_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonVote.Click

    If CheckBoxBarton.CheckState = 1 And CheckBoxMartin.CheckState = 1 And CheckBoxRichards.CheckState = 1 Then
        MsgBox("Don't vote for more than 2")
        CheckBoxBarton.Checked = False
        CheckBoxMartin.Checked = False
        CheckBoxRichards.Checked = False
    End If

    If CheckBoxBarton.Checked Then
        intCountBarton += 1
    End If

    If CheckBoxMartin.Checked Then
        intCountMartin = intCountMartin + 1
    End If

    If CheckBoxRichards.Checked Then
        intCountRichards = intCountRichards + 1
    End If

    CheckBoxBarton.Checked = False
    CheckBoxMartin.Checked = False
    CheckBoxRichards.Checked = False

End Sub

Private Sub ButtonResult_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonResult.Click

    MsgBox("Barton: " & intCountBarton & vbNewLine & "Martin: " & intCountMartin & vbNewLine & "Richards: " & intCountRichards)

End Sub

Private Sub ButtonReset_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonReset.Click

    CheckBoxBarton.Checked = False
    CheckBoxMartin.Checked = False
    CheckBoxRichards.Checked = False

    intCountBarton = 0
    intCountMartin = 0
    intCountRichards = 0

End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim Count_Barton As Integer = 0
    Dim Count_Martin As Integer = 0
    Dim Count_Richards As Integer = 0

Private Sub Btn_Cast_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn_Cast.Click
    Dim Counter As Integer = 0 'NOT SURE WHAT THIS IS DOING... NOT BEING USED
    If ChkBox_Barton.CheckState = 1 And ChkBox_Martin.CheckState = 1 And ChkBox_Richards.CheckState = 1 Then
        MsgBox("Don't vote for more than 2")
    Else
        If ChkBox_Barton.Checked Then Count_Barton += 1

        If ChkBox_Martin.Checked = 1 Then Count_Martin += 1

        If ChkBox_Richards.CheckState = 1 Then Count_Richards += 1

    End If     

End Sub
```

Comment: I take your point on the popup issue and have amended code to fix this.... as for the other comment... In VB... an If statement can be used without and end if when the whole statement is on one line....